# When are XAML events unhooked?

Tags: wpf, events, windows-phone-8, memory-management, windows-phone

I am currently working on a Windows Phone 8 application that uses images a lot, so keeping memory usage low is a must.

In an attempt to make sure the memory usage stays low I am trying to make sure events are unhooked from as efficiently as possible, along with other things of course.

So the question becomes which is more memory efficient?

Doing the hooking/Unhooking in the OnNavigatedTo and OnNavigatedFrom events like so:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    MyButton.Click += MyButton_Click(...)
}

protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    MyButton.Click -= MyButton_Click(...)
}
```

Or is xaml smart enough to unhook an event that was defined in the xaml like so:

```
<Button x:Name="MyButton" Click="MyButton_Click"/>
```

after the page have been navigated away from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the scenario you listed -- XAML file with an event handler in the code-behind -- both the event owner and handler belong to the same (partial) class.  That means, you don't have to worry about explicitly removing the event handler.  As soon as the page is unloaded (navigated from), it should become eligible for garbage collection.

The scenario where memory leaks become a problem is where:

1. the event handler and the event itself are owned by different objects
2. the owner of the *event* is long-lived, and the owner of the *handler* is short-lived

In this scenario, since a subscribed event causes the event owner to hold a reference to the handler owner, it prevents the latter from being garbage collected.  This is where [weak events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970850.aspx) are useful -- a weak event reference allows the handler object to be garbage collected if the only remaining references are weak event listeners.